# TortoiseHg: Don't display ancestors in keyword search results

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to search my Mercurial repository for commits with a certain log message (e.g. "merge") using TortoiseHg.
This is my repository without any search:

[image]

And when I search for "merge" I get this:

[image]

So it seems like the search finds the first match and displays all of its ancestors. Filtering of non-matched change-sets it turned on:

[image]

I only want to see the matching ancestors. It works for a colleague of mine, but we couldn't find what's different between our environments. We both use version 3.9 on Windows 10 x64 with the same extensions.

Here's another example searching for "works!":

[image]

And using keyword specifically:

[image]

And filtering by author:

[image]

It just always finds the first match and displays all the ancestors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled TortoiseHg, deleted all of its files from the machine (AppData, configurations, etc.) and reinstalled from scratch and now it seems to work. Since I already tried reinstalling a month ago I guess that cleaning all the files helped.

Answer (score 0):

> So it seems like the search finds the first match and displays all of its ancestors

No, you miss here. Plain-text pattern TEXT in search means (internally) using predicate `keyword()` in revset, `hg log -T {rev}^M -r keyword('merge')` in your case. But:

```
"keyword(string)"
  Search commit message, user name, and names of changed files for
  string. The match is case-insensitive.
```

Search is wider, than you expect. Just compare with my repo, there "merge" is only part of log-message: only two direct relatives appeared in revset, because they both met condition

[image]

For "merge" only in log `matching()` may be better, but if you really want **mergesets** `merge()` is **The Natural Way (tm)**, and final revset for mergests and it's parents may be

```
merge() or parents(merge())
```

Comment: I only gave "merge" as an example for a search string. I'm actually searching for something else. But I still don't understand what you're saying. Why would I get a revision with commit message "Works!" or "add prints for debugging". Your example makes sense because you have the word "merge" in both revisions you circled... Most of my revisions don't have "merge" in them.

Comment: @Dina - because "Search commit message, user name, and names of changed files..." - check these revisions for intersections. Or show `log -v` for this part of repo here. I have file "Seeker.txt" in repo, keyword "see" may produce unexpected result, if I'll think only abt log-message

Comment: There's no "merge" anywhere else. Moreover, as I said, I'm actually searching for a different longer phrase, *and* it works for a colleague on the same repository!

Comment: I added more screenshots of the behavior.

Comment: @Dina - matching() results are really weird. Can you create new clone of repo and test in it (I think about some repo-specific local aliases on the rights of delirium)?

Comment: It's the same for all my repos. I will try later to clone from scratch. I also thought of completely uninstalling and reinstalling TortoiseHg. Will try a few things and report.

Comment: OK, was too curious not to try right now. Cloning to a clean location didn't help. Will try reinstalling later.